# displays data on which search words used in MOSS

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I need to write a webpart that displays data, on which search words used for the MOSS and how often used.
 From where I can read this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use search query logging?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262541%28office.12%29.aspx

1. On the SSP home page, in the Office SharePoint Usage Reporting section, click Usage reporting.
2. On the Configure Advanced Usage Analysis Processing page, in the Processing Settings section, click Enable advanced usage analysis processing.
3. In the Search Query Logging section, select Enable search query logging.
4. Click OK.